# error when input row height with vertical and horizontal merged cell table in word vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to use InputBox to set the given parameter to change the table row height on cursor now position or the highlighted area. I could do this when I highlighted multi-row by mouse, but I also would like to do the same thing when I just put my cursor in a specific single row in the word table. However, when it comes to a table with vertically merged cells, I couldn't do that. VBA would show the error message: Run time error:'5991'. Is there any way to modify the row height or column width among a table with vertical and horizontal merged cells table?

Here is the script I propose:

```
Sub TableChangeSelectedRowHeight()
PromptBottom = "Input Row Height for Selection _________ mm"
HeaderTop = "Adjust Row Height"
UserData = InputBox(PromptBottom, HeaderTop)

Dim ToPoint As Single
ToPoint = Application.CentimetersToPoints(UserData / 10)

If StrPtr(UserData) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "您取消輸入。"
ElseIf UserData = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "您沒有輸入資料。"
    End
Else
If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) = True And Selection.Rows.Count <> 1 Then 'for mutltiple row
        Selection.Cells.SetHeight RowHeight:=ToPoint, _
        HeightRule:=wdRowHeightAtLeast

ElseIf Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) = True And 
    Selection.Rows.Count = 1 Then 'for single row
        aa = Selection.Cells(1).RowIndex
        Selection.Rows(aa).SetHeight RowHeight:=ToPoint, _ 
        HeightRule:=wdRowHeightAtLeast 'There are some problems here 
Else
        MsgBox "The insertion point is not in a table."
End If

End If

End Sub
```

and when I conduct the sub the following error message would show:

```
Run time error:5991
Cannot access individual rows in the collection because the table has vertically merged cells.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along the lines of:

```
Dim Cl As Cell, Rng As Range, r As Long
With Selection
  If .Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
    For r = .Cells(1).RowIndex To .Cells(.Cells.Count).RowIndex
      Set Rng = Nothing
      With .Tables(1)
        For Each Cl In .Range.Cells
          With Cl
            If .RowIndex = r Then
              If Rng Is Nothing Then
                Set Rng = .Range
              Else
                Rng.End = .Range.End
              End If
            End If
          End With
        Next
        Rng.Cells.HeightRule = wdRowHeightAtLeast
        Rng.Cells.Height = CentimetersToPoints(UserData / 10)
      End With
    Next
  Else
    MsgBox "The insertion point is not in a table."
  End If
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I appreciate great work for that. Could you give your brief comment or interpretation of the logic or operation way about handling the table in Word VBA? I couldn't really understand the difference or key point on it. Again, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I know in your script, for my viewpoint, it just tries to run cell by cell. I am curious about why MS VBA can not accept to just direct point the index of row to set the row height.

Comment: You would have to ask Microsoft why they didn't write VBA to handle vertically-merged rows with vertically-merged cells in situations like this. Clearly, they recognised there was an issues, which is why you get the 'Run time error 5991' message. My code works by resizing the available cells instead of trying to resize the row.